# Maple display settings for matrix output

Tags: settings, maple

I am working in maple and my output is matrices, which were displayed in the workbook.

A coworker was looking at my code and changed a setting for the output of matrices (in format or view, it was a  drop down) that changed the format of the output matrix. He said it would run faster. The matrix is still visible but in a collapsed way.

I cannot remember the setting he changed. Does anyone know which setting I am talking about?

Answer (score 0):

There is an `interface` setting `rtablesize` which controls how small a Matrix needs to be before it will display in full. If either dimension is greater than the value of that setting then a placeholder is displayed instead.

For example,

```
restart;

interface(rtablesize); # default is 10

                                 10

m:=LinearAlgebra:-RandomMatrix(6,3);

                             [ 57  -32   99]
                             [             ]
                             [ 27  -74   29]
                             [             ]
                             [-93   -4   44]
                        m := [             ]
                             [-76   27   92]
                             [             ]
                             [-72    8  -31]
                             [             ]
                             [ -2   69   67]

interface(rtablesize=5):

m;

                      [ 6 x 3 Matrix         ]
                      [ Data Type: anything  ]
                      [ Storage: rectangular ]
                      [ Order: Fortran_order ]
```

I am not aware of any way to change this setting from the menubar, with just the mouse.

There is an option in the menubar (eg. On MS-Windows, from the menu item Tools->Options) which controls the elision of long output (ie. long results get displayed with triple-dot ellipsis). But that is likely not what you're after.

Note that making such changes can affect how quickly the interface (eg. the "GUI" or Graphical User Interface) renders large results. But it doesn't affect computation speed.

If you don't want large results displayed then the easiest thing to do is to terminate your Maple statements (commands) with a full colon (instead of terminating with a semicolon, or with nothing).